# Referencing named range from many columns away within same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to reference a named range in a sheet from multiple columns down in a different cell.

The named range is the following:

[image]

When I reference this named range from column D or E, I get expected result from the named range:

[image]

When I reference this name range from column Z, for example, I get the following result:

[image]

How do I reference a named range from columns outside those that are within the named range?

Comment: Let's try something like `={named range, Z1:Z100}` to add more column, I'm not sure I understand correctly. Or let me see the named range of `column Z` you mentioned that's error. Or more detail might be needed

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Use the `INDEX` formula to reference a named range outside the range columns. Inside the range columns this operation is automatic, but only if the range is a row using the selected column as index.

So for example if you have your range in D5:E5 called "Numbers" you can reference the "Numbers" first cell typing `="Numbers"` in the D column.

To reproduce this behavior on multidimensional ranges and from outside the range colums you will have to use the `INDEX` function like this:

`INDEX("Numbers",1,1)` => This will return the first cell of "Numbers".

You can also reference the entire row or column by omitting one index:

`INDEX("Numbers",1,)` => This will return the 1st row of "Numbers".